# Use execv & ptrace to execute a selenium-webdriver python program in linux

Tags: python, c, linux, selenium-webdriver, ptrace

I wrote a C program below which used `execv` to run a shell command and `ptrace` to trace it.

```
    pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) {
        // child process
        ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, 0, NULL, NULL);
        char** argv = new char*[3];
        argv[0] = "/usr/bin/python3.6";
        argv[1] = "pythoncode.py";
        argv[2] = NULL;
        execv(argv[0], argv);
    } else
    {
        // parent process
        pid_t p = wait4(-1, &stat, __WALL, &rusage_);
        ...
    }
```

It can work properly when I use it to run normal python code. But today, I wrote a python code below

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    browser = webdriver.Chrome()
    # do something
    browser.close()
```

I can ran it successfully in a shell or without `ptrace`, but when I used `execv` and `ptrace` simultaneously, it always give me a stop signal and signal code was `SIGILL`(Illegal Instruction). Does anyone know why and how to solve it?

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/ Unclear what exactly your "C program" does and how it interacts with the code you've shown. Thus impossible to answer as the Q is now.

Comment: Sorry, I have added my C program now.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/766 What do the signal details say: where does this happen, what's the source code that directly triggers the signal?